# matlab how to get min value and its index in a matrix

Tags: matlab, min

I have a matrix let's say like this

```
A=[1 3 6 2 0 4
   6 8 9 5 1 4
   7 2 7 8 9 2]
```

I want to get the minimal value where the row is given (`r`) and the column is in an interval (`[c.. c+x]`). Also I want the index (number of column of it).
I can get the min with

```
MinVal=min(A(r,c:c+x))
```

Example

```
MinVal=min(A(2,3:3+2))
```

will give me

```
 % MinVal= 1
```

The index of this MinVal is `I= 5` since it is in the 5th column (I know already the row and don't need it).

But how to get this index ?

If I do like this, I don't get what I want

```
 [MinVal,I]=min(A(r,c:c+x))
```

Comment: Btw, the value in I does not correspond to the sum of the number of row and column, it is the column number where the minimum value is, for me it returned 3, which is the location of 1 in the submatrix

Comment: yes I made a mistake, I changed it. Yes, but i want the location in the whole matrix not the submatrix. I want it to give 5 for this example not 3.

Comment: `[MinVal,I] = min(A(r,c:c+x))` and `I += (c - 1)` should do it...? (and yes, my matlab is too rusty to combine the two expressions into a single one)

Comment: Thanks, I did it like this but was thinking maybe there was a one line way to get it from the start.

Comment: Ok, with two lines is still not long either :). Just wanted to check if a shorter way existed. Anyway, you can put it in an answer so that I accept it.

Comment: @studentbeginner Yeah with the way MATLAB works, the best you can do is two lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the shortest code, but an easy to understand possibility:

Create a mask indicating which variables you use in your submatrix:

```
 M=false(size(A));
 M(r,c:c+x)=true; %use the same indexing operation
```

Convert to linear indices:

```
M=find(M);
```

And use it to translate I to indices in the full matrix:

```
M(I)
```