# matlab the index of the next smallest element in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I could get the minimum value and its index like in here [matlab how to get min value and its index in a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35996953/matlab-how-to-get-min-value-and-its-index-in-a-matrix?noredirect=1#comment59646507_35996953).

From a matrix A

```
A=[1 3 6 2 0 4
   6 8 9 5 1 3
   7 2 7 8 9 2]
```

To get the minimal value `MinVal`(where the row is given (r) and the column is in an interval ([c.. c+x]) and the index `ind` (number of column of it)). I have to do

```
[MinVal,I]=min(A(r,c:c+x))
 ind= c-1+I;
```

Example

```
[MinVal, ind]=min(A(2,3:3+2))
will give me

 % MinVal= 1
 % ind =5
```

Then I have

```
B.state=[ 0
          0
          1
          0
          1]
```

So here `I` can't take `ind=5` because `B(5).state==1`, I need to move to the next `MinVal= 5` and `ind = 4`. Here, it is ok, I can stop but if `B(4).state ==1`, then I need to move the next smallest and so on

But then the problem is that I have another structure `B` where I am going to check if `B(ind).state== 1` then I have to move to the next smallest element and get its index and so on until I find the first empty one.

If I try like this

```
        MinD = A(r,c:c+x);
        [MinVal,Ind]=min(MinD);
        ind= nbrT+Ind;

        MinD2 = sort(MinD(:));
        p=2;
        while (B(ind).state == 1)
            MinVal= MinD2(p);
            %need to get the new index 
            %something like this
            ind=find (A == MinVal) ;
            p=p+1;
        end
```

The problem is that I can get the next minimum value but the index I will get can be of more than one value if MinVal appears more than once so how can I get the one with `state == 0`
I don't want to use unique either because even if I have two different elements with the same minimum, they refer to two different places and I have to keep both (I can use the second one if the first one is full).
Modified code to

```
MinD = A(r,c:c+x); 
[MinVal,Ind]=min(MinD); 
ind= nbrT+Ind; 
[MinD2, IndMinD2] = sort(MinD(:)); 
p=2; 
while (B(ind).state == 1) 
    MinVal=MinD2(p); 
    Ind=IndMind2(p); 
    p=p+1; 
end
Ind= c-1+Ind;
```

So how can I do it?

Comment: when does `state` switch from 1 to 0?

Comment: I have it somewhere else in my code. So here, I have already the states at either 0(empty) or 1 (for full) and I want to pick one that is minimal and empty.

Comment: so here, if you have multiple zero states you have multiple minima. you wanna pick the one that comes earlier in your array?

Comment: If you have to repeatedly go through each next-smallest value, I think doing pre-[`sort`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) with the associated sorting index is the way to go.  Then you just step linearly through the sorted vector.

Comment: I did like this ` MinD = A(r,c:c+x);
        [MinVal,Ind]=min(MinD);
        ind= nbrT+Ind;
        [MinD2, IndMinD2] = sort(MinD(:));
        p=2;
        while (B(ind).state == 1)
            MinVal=MinD2(p);
            Ind=IndMind2(p);
            p=p+1;
        end Ind= c-1+Ind; `

Comment: The example has cleared some things up, but I still have three questions: (1) Is `B` a struct array (such that `B(ind).state` refers to an array)?  (2) What is the end goal output of the loop (it looks like it's `p`, but it's not clear.) ?  (3) I think an example output of `r = 3`, `c = 2`, and `x = 4` would be more instructive; could you augment your example to include that?

Comment: (1)yes, (2)What I need is the index (with a state =0) of the minVal not p.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
           MinD2 = MinD(:));

           for ii=1:numel(MinD2)

              [MinVal,Ind]=min(MinD2);

              %do you stuff with the index 
              %and at the end do this:
              MinD2(Ind)=Inf;

           end
```

Comment: I don't think this will give me what I want. I tried to explain better with an example. See the edit of my question.